# What is the default binding of wsimport?

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport

I used wsimport to generate my client stubs. My code for wsimport is like this:

```
wsimport -wsdllocation webservice.wsdl -keep webservice.wsdl -B-XautoNameResolution
```

What binding do I use? Am I using JAXB? How do I know if I'm using JAXB?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is the standard binding layer for [**JAX-WS (JSR-224)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224) implementations.  You will know that you are using JAXB if the generated domain model has annotations from the `javax.xml.bind.annotation` package.